# ExecutorService giving out of memory error

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an ArrayList which has billions of records, I iterate over each record and post this to a server. The method called as follows in each iteration:

```
public void sendNotification(String url, String accountId, String accountPwd, String jsonPayLoad,
            int maxConnections) {
        notificationService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxConnections);
        notificationService.submit(new SendPushNotification(url, accountId, accountPwd, jsonPayLoad));
        notificationService.shutdown();

    }
```

My SendPushNotification class is as follows:

```
public class SendPushNotification implements Runnable {

    String url;
    String accountId;
    String accountPwd;
    String jsonPayLoad;

    public SendPushNotification(String url, String accountId, String accountPwd, String jsonPayLoad) {
        this.url = url;
        this.accountId = accountId;
        this.accountPwd = accountPwd;
        this.jsonPayLoad = jsonPayLoad;

    }
    public void run() {

        HttpsURLConnection conn = null;
        try {

            StringBuffer response;
            URL url1 = new URL(url);
            conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
            // conn.setReadTimeout(20000);
            // conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setRequestProperty("X-Account-Id", accountId);
            conn.setRequestProperty("X-Passcode", accountPwd);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(jsonPayLoad);
            writer.close();
            out.close();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            System.out.println(String.valueOf(responseCode));
            switch (responseCode) {
            case 200:
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                response = new StringBuffer();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                System.out.println(response.toString());
            }
        } catch (IOException ez) {
            ez.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    }
```

So whats going wrong here, I suspect I have to run this on a decent system configuration. Basically I want to understand if there is anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Oh I am instantiating the Executor service again and again! Shifting that to my main method!

Comment: Just out of curiosity ... how did you go about this problem in the end?

Comment: Long back, I used a pooled connection essentially doing a handshake just once throughout the lifecycle of the application. Since Ive changed companies and forgotten about it :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrong approach! Looping over:

```
notificationService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxConnections);
```

is a **bad** idea! Why do you intend to create **billions** of ThreadPools; to submit **one** task to then shut it down?! That's like buying a **new** Ferrari every time the ash tray is full ...

Please understand: your simple code creates quite a bunch of objects; and all of them go away after one loop iteration. Meaning: they become eligible for garbage collection. In other words: you are **constantly** creating **garbage** on a very high rate. And you are really surprised that doing so pushes you into "out of memory"?

Instead, use **one** ThreadPool and submit your billions of requests into that!

And beyond that, even that isn't exactly a great idea. Opening **one** network connection to your server per entry will simply **not** scale up to **billions** of entries: a **real** solution requires you to step back and think up something that works in a "reasonable way" end to end. For example you should consider to create some kind of "bulk" or "streaming" interface on your server. Iterating a billions-entry file on the client, and making billions of connections to the server is sorry, *insane*!

So instead of doing:

```
loop:
  open connection / push ONE item / close connection
```

You better go for:

```
open connection / push all items / close connections
```

Or beyond that, you might even look into transmitting compressed, binary data. Meaning: compress your file on the client side, send it as blob; and extract / process it on the server side.

A lot of option space here; but be assured: your current "out of memory" exception is just one symptom caused by an "inappropriate" design.

EDIT: given your comment, my (personal) advice:

- Obviously: use **one** threadpool (probably built on 3 threads) and push your Runnables into that shared pool
- Then start careful profiling. Given the fact that you intend to process those billions of entries, each millisecond might count. In other words: do reasonable testing and find out how "good" that solution is. And if it doesn't work out; do profiling in order to find spots that need improvement.
- The key thing to understand: you can probably fine-tune things, and gain 1%  here and 5% there; but it could well happen that all of that is simply not good enough. When you do things a billion times, then they **ought** to be really fast; otherwise that factor will kill you ...

Comment: Hi I really love the idea, but the server is not in my control. The server accepts only one payload at a time however I can make three concurrent requests from one ip.

Comment: You are welcome. I put in some updates. I guess you should do measurements first to assess if this architecture *could* work out theoretically. If you find "this will never scale" then there is no other option than **changing** the whole architecture. What is the point of using "this server" when the server can't support the requirements (push billions of entries to it). In other words: you want to solve your problem. And if "that server" prevents the solution, then it has to go!

Comment: Corporates brother corporates! I wish things were more under my control. However your advise has helped a lot and thanks mate, cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

> ExecutorService giving out of memory error

As @GhostCat pointed out you should create one `ExecutorService` at the top of notification class at the start of your program.  As you get new requests in, you submit all of your notification requests to the *same* `ExecutorService` which will create threads as necessary.  Creating a new pool each time through is a bad pattern.

```
// at top of class not in the sending loop 
private final ExecutorService notificationThreadPool =
     Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_CONNECTIONS);
```

However it's important to realize that you might still run out of memory because the thread-pool uses an unbounded queue.  The `newFixedThreadPool(...)` method under the covers uses `new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()` so if your sender is not keeping up with demand you will still run out of memory.

Then if increasing the number of threads is not an option, you are going to have to either slow down the producer somehow or write the requests to disk or other short-term storage.

If you need to use a bounded queue to detect when things are filling up then you should do something like:

```
private final ExecutorService notificationThreadPool =
     new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                            new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(MAX_QUEUED_REQUESTS);
```

By default, if all of the threads are busy and the queue is full when you submit a `SendPushNotification` to the pool it will throw `RejectedExecutionException` if it is full giving you the opportunity to handle that somehow.  You can also use `notificationThreadPool.setRejectedExecutionHandler(...)` to set a `RejectedExecutionHandler` that writes the rejected notification into temporary storage until the threads catch up.